# Scope of typedefs

Tags: c

I am not at a computer so cannot test this at the moment but have some code to review. I'm still somewhat in a C++ mindframe unfortunatley.

So, when a typedef is declared within a C source file what is its scope? I am aware that to make functions and variables only available within the same translation unit you need to make them static and I was wondering if this is the same for typedefs?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Typedefs are declarations. If you have a typedef in a C file, no other C file will be aware of that since they are compiled indepedendly of each other.

For a typedef in a header, it will of course be visible from all C files that include it.

Comment: Helpful, but was the OP (as I am) looking for clarity on relevance of ODR in C vs C++. i.e. having made a typedef in a source file can that generate a naming clash elsewhere?

Answer (score 6):

`typedef` has the same scope as regular variables in C/C++

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example showing typedef and scope:

```
typedef int foo_t;

foo_t x = 1;

double bar(double x) {
    typedef double foo_t;
    foo_t y = 2.0;
    return y + 3.14156;
}

foo_t z = 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

I dont know whats the meaning of this complex sentence but this is how C standard defines the scope of typedefs:

> As a special case, a type name (which is not a declaration of an identifier) is considered to
>   have a scope that begins just after the place within the type name where the omitted
>   identifier would appear were it not omitted.

P.S. Somebody please explain.